# Angular2 - Argument of type 'QueryList<ElementRef>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular

I am trying to recreate the following plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/RJJdcY?p=preview, but when I have the following code in Angular2, I get the error message **"Argument of type 'QueryList<ElementRef>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'."**

Here is my code as it stands now, does anyone have a suggestion, seeing that I do not know if I am using something that is maybe outdated.

```
import { OnInit, ViewChild, ViewChildren, Component, QueryList, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nlr-container-test-container',
  template: `
  <h2>Hello</h2>
  <input #myname (input)="updateName(myname.value)" value="John Doe">

  <div #div1></div>
  <div #div2></div>
  <div #div3></div>

`,
  styleUrls: ['./container-test-container.component.css']
})
export class ContainerTestContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @ViewChild('myname') input:ElementRef; 

  @ViewChildren('div1,div2,div3') divs: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  //@ViewChildren('.plates', {read: ElementRef}) 
  //public books: QueryList<ElementRef>

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.input.nativeElement.value);
    console.debug(this.divs);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Thanks you very much.

Comment: How can the error be reproduces. I don't get the error in the Plunker.

Comment: I get it when I have the above code in my angular2 editor, and then try and run it on the server to view it in my browser. I copied the code from the plunker into my editor to play around with it, but I can not get it to run.

Comment: Can you make the Plunker so that the error occurs?

Comment: No, I can not reproduce the error in Plunker, even if I copy my whole page of code into the Plunker it still works there, but not when I run it on my ng serve. So sorry for asking a stupid question, but if I copy that page scr/app.ts over to an angular2 component that I have, is there anything else on the other pages that I also need to copy over? In my editors app.module.ts the component is declared and imported...

Comment: The error message doesn't indicate that you are missing something. Can you provide more details like what code line exactly causes the error message?

Comment: I hope this will mean something, but here is the whole error I get in my browser: Error: Module build failed: Error: D:/Websites/News/news/src/app/container-test-container/container-test-container.component.ts (29,19): Argument of type 'QueryList<ElementRef>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.)
    at _checkDiagnostics (D:\Websites\News\news\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:145:15)
    at D:\Websites\News\news\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:172:17

Comment: What is the code at `D:/Websites/News/news/src/app/container-test-container/conta‌​iner-test-container.‌​component.ts (29,19)`?

Comment: PS, the (29,19) that is in the error, does the 29 stand for the line in the file that the error is in? And then what does the 19 mean?

Comment: 29 is line, 19 is column

Comment: Here is line 29: console.debug(this.divs);

Comment: I see. Try `console.log(this.divs)` instead.

Comment: 100%!!! Thanks man, that was very nice of you!! Is that line deprecated code? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I only use `console.log()` and never tried `console.debug()`. I'm using Dart most of the time and debugging Dart is a bit different than JS/TS anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**console.debug(this.divs)** should be changed to **console.log(this.divs)**

Thanks to Gunter!